# IOS/Objective-C: Error Converting JSON to Object

Tags: ios, json, kvc

I am trying to convert JSON array to object for display in table.  I am able to capture JSON.  However, when I try to turn into object, I get error shown below. There is definitely a property named "name" in object class.

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData 
                                                         options:kNilOptions
                                                           error:&error];
    NSMutableArray* latestItems = nil;
    latestItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    latestItems = [json objectForKey:@"items"];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    for (int i = 0; i < latestItems.count; i++)
    {
        NSDictionary *itemElement = latestItems[i];
        // Create a new l object and set its props to todoElement properties
        IDItemFromServer *newItem = [[IDItemFromServer alloc] init];
//ERROR  NEXT LINE THROWS FOLLOWING ERROR
//'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<IDItemFromServer 0x14e88010> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.'
       [newItem setValue:@"hi" forKey:@"name"];
       [newItem setValue:itemElement[@"address"] forKey:@"address"];

        // Add this new item  to the array
        [latestItems addObject:newItem];
    }
```

Would appreciate any suggestions on how to fix error.

Edit:

```
//Object.h file
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface IDItemFromServer : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * iid;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * address;

@end
```

Comment: The error indicates there is not a property named `name`. Update your question with details about the interface for the `IDItemFromServer` class.

Comment: If you have a nice public property, why not simply use `newItem.name = @"hi";` instead of using `setValue:forKey:`?

Comment: I was trying this before and it was giving me //[IDItemFromServer setName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16d7dfd0
error, however, I will try it again.

Comment: yes it is throwing IDItemFromServer setName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15599ed0' that way

Comment: Something is off. The `IDItemFromServer` interface you posted claims there is such a property but at runtime there clearly is no such property. Must be some strange core data issue and I've never used core data.

Comment: In the .m file there was a @dynamic name.  I have commented this out and now error seems to be gone.  (There is another error but past that line.)  Don't know why dynamic would have caused error.

Comment: You only want `@dynamic` when the property is synthesized at runtime instead of compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says **IDItemFromServer** has no property **name**. add the **name,address** property like bellow code

```
In IDItemFromServer.h file

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface IDItemFromServer : NSObject

@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString name;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString address;

@end
```

In IDItemFromServer.m file

```
#import "IDItemFromServer.h"

@implementation IDItemFromServer

@synthesize name;
@synthesize address;

@end
```

Comment: 1) The question shows the interface for `IDItemFromServer` and it does have a `name` property. 2) Why are you calling `@synthesize`? That hasn't been needed for a few years now.

Comment: Thanks for drawing attention to .m file.